# Visual C++ examine object instances size in the process memory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I wish to know what is the overall memory consumed in runtime by all instances of a specific type.
I mean,I am using [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see how much memory consumes specific process.But I would also like to know what objects and how much memory they consume inside the process.

Comment: The notion of 'memory consumed by all instances of an object' is vague, due to fragmentation.  You'd discover that *Lots* of memory is lost in small-ish slots between your explicit allocations, that isn't usable and is not addressable to any specific object type.

Comment: Tools that drill into and report upon some aspect of a program's performance (typically CPU usage) while it is running are called 'profilers'. What you're looking for might thus be referred to as a "memory profiler". Searching Google for [`c++ "memory profiler"`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%2B%2B+"memory+profiler") might be a good start for finding a tool that will help you.

Comment: The memory profile which comes with VS2012 does not supply info on memory consumption by the objects.If I am wrong please correct me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some memory leas detector tools can do this, such as [Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/tutorials/cpp-memory-validator/tutorial-filter-object.php). It is not free, you can download a trial version and try it.

If you just want to find memory leaks, [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42933) from MS is a good choice.

Another way is to override new and delete for the object you want to monitor,  thus you can track the memory usage.

Comment: Thanks.No,I don't look for memory leaks detector.I want to inspect how much memory consume objects in the process.

Comment: Memory Validator was what I needed.Thanks.